# Asp.net web applications in non-IIS server?

Tags: asp.net, tomcat, iis, jboss, webserver

I would like to know whether asp.net applications can host in any non-IIS web/application server like Tomcat/JBoss/Glassfish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to deploy a JEE application (WAR, EAR) directly to IIS, the answer is no.

IIS can however act as front-server for a JEE server (Tomcat/JBoss/Glassfish) using the [IIS connector](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/iis.html). This means you need to have a running installation of Tomcat/JBoss/Glassfish; this will not be listening for connections from the outside world. Requests from the outside will hit IIS, which will forward them to Tomcat/JBoss/Glassfish.